# Terraform Plan Command Stuck

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have installed Terraform v1.1.7 and operating it using Visual Studio Code in Windows 10.

When I run any sample templates (using any provider like azure/local etc), the init works but the terraform plan and apply gets stuck for hours and does not give any output. I have tried all ways (re-install etc). I tried to looks at the trace logs and unable to find out the issue,

TERRAFORM CODE

```
resource "local_file" "demo" { 
         name = "1.txt" 
         content = "Hello World" 
}
```

TERRAFORM CODE ERROR

```
2022-03-11T17:06:18.509+0530 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.1.7
2022-03-11T17:06:18.509+0530 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.17.2
2022-03-11T17:06:18.509+0530 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"C:\\Users\\SushantaChakraborty\\Desktop\\tf\\terraform.exe", "plan"}
2022-03-11T17:06:18.512+0530 [TRACE] Stdout is not a terminal
2022-03-11T17:06:18.512+0530 [TRACE] Stderr is a terminal of width 155
2022-03-11T17:06:18.513+0530 [TRACE] Stdin is a terminal
2022-03-11T17:06:18.522+0530 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: C:\Users\SushantaChakraborty\AppData\Roaming\terraform.rc
2022-03-11T17:06:18.523+0530 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2022-03-11T17:06:18.524+0530 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory terraform.d/plugins
2022-03-11T17:06:18.525+0530 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory C:\Users\SushantaChakraborty\AppData\Roaming\terraform.d\plugins      
2022-03-11T17:06:18.526+0530 [DEBUG] ignoring non-existing provider search directory C:\Users\SushantaChakraborty\AppData\Roaming\HashiCorp\Terraform\plugins
2022-03-11T17:06:18.526+0530 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"plan"}
2022-03-11T17:06:18.534+0530 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: no config given or present on disk, so returning nil config
2022-03-11T17:06:18.535+0530 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend has not previously been initialized in this working directory
2022-03-11T17:06:18.535+0530 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "b61e8a78-e15f-ef87-8c9e-d78d607de4c3"
2022-03-11T17:06:18.536+0530 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using default local state only (no backend configuration, and no existing initialized backend)
2022-03-11T17:06:18.536+0530 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type <nil>
2022-03-11T17:06:18.538+0530 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform\providers
2022-03-11T17:06:18.548+0530 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.2.1 for windows_amd64 at .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\local\2.2.1\windows_amd64
2022-03-11T17:06:18.554+0530 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\local\2.2.1\windows_amd64 
as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local 2.2.1
2022-03-11T17:06:19.953+0530 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2022-03-11T17:06:19.954+0530 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "C:\\Users\\SushantaChakraborty\\Desktop\\tf"
2022-03-11T17:06:19.955+0530 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend <nil> does not support operations, so wrapping it in a local backend
2022-03-11T17:06:19.956+0530 [INFO]  backend/local: starting Plan operation
2022-03-11T17:06:19.957+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state manager for workspace "default"
2022-03-11T17:06:19.957+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: state manager for workspace "default" will:
 - read initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
 - write new snap`enter code here`shots to terraform.tfstate
 - create any backup at terraform.tfstate.backup
2022-03-11T17:06:19.958+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
2022-03-11T17:06:25.543+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: preparing to manage state snapshots at terraform.tfstate
2022-03-11T17:06:25.545+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: no previously-stored snapshot exists
2022-03-11T17:06:25.546+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: locking terraform.tfstate using LockFileEx
2022-03-11T17:06:25.546+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing lock metadata to .terraform.tfstate.lock.info
2022-03-11T17:06:25.549+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: reading remote state for workspace "default"
2022-03-11T17:06:25.549+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: reading latest snapshot from terraform.tfstate
2022-03-11T17:06:25.550+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: snapshot file has nil snapshot, but that's okay
2022-03-11T17:06:25.550+0530 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: read nil snapshot
2022-03-11T17:06:25.551+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: populating backend.LocalRun for current working directory
2022-03-11T17:06:25.553+0530 [TRACE] Config.VerifyDependencySelections: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local has 2.2.1 to satisfy ""
2022-03-11T17:06:25.554+0530 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: starting
2022-03-11T17:06:25.554+0530 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: complete
2022-03-11T17:06:25.554+0530 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting interactive input, if necessary
2022-03-11T17:06:25.555+0530 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local"
2022-03-11T17:06:25.555+0530 [TRACE] terraform.contextPlugins: Initializing provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local" to read its schema
2022-03-11T17:06:25.556+0530 [DEBUG] created provider logger: level=trace
2022-03-11T17:06:25.556+0530 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2022-03-11T17:06:25.596+0530 [DEBUG] provider: starting plugin: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.2.1/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe args=[.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.2.1/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe]
2022-03-11T17:06:27.337+0530 [DEBUG] provider: plugin started: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.2.1/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe pid=23380
2022-03-11T17:06:27.338+0530 [DEBUG] provider: waiting for RPC address: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.2.1/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe
2022-03-11T17:06:30.099+0530 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.098+0530
2022-03-11T17:06:30.164+0530 [DEBUG] provider: using plugin: version=5
2022-03-11T17:06:30.167+0530 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: plugin address: address=127.0.0.1:10000 network=tcp timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.164+0530
2022-03-11T17:06:30.242+0530 [TRACE] provider.stdio: waiting for stdio data
2022-03-11T17:06:30.242+0530 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: GetProviderSchema
2022-03-11T17:06:30.243+0530 [TRACE] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: Received request: @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.5.0/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:329 tf_proto_version=5 @module=sdk.proto tf_provider_addr=provider tf_req_id=5a0134e9-eb48-03f5-a2ec-5fe6f4211828 tf_rpc=GetSchema timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.243+0530
2022-03-11T17:06:30.244+0530 [TRACE] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: Calling downstream: tf_provider_addr=provider @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.5.0/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:336 @module=sdk.proto tf_proto_version=5 tf_req_id=5a0134e9-eb48-03f5-a2ec-5fe6f4211828 tf_rpc=GetSchema timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.243+0530
2022-03-11T17:06:30.244+0530 [TRACE] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: Called downstream: @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.5.0/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:342 tf_proto_version=5 tf_provider_addr=provider @module=sdk.proto tf_req_id=5a0134e9-eb48-03f5-a2ec-5fe6f4211828 tf_rpc=GetSchema timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.243+0530
2022-03-11T17:06:30.245+0530 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: Close
2022-03-11T17:06:30.245+0530 [TRACE] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.2.1_x5.exe: Served request: tf_rpc=GetSchema @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.5.0/tfprotov5/tf5server/server.go:348 @module=sdk.proto tf_req_id=5a0134e9-eb48-03f5-a2ec-5fe6f4211828 tf_proto_version=5 tf_provider_addr=provider timestamp=2022-03-11T17:06:30.243+0530`
```

Comment: can you share the terraform code itself?

Comment: 'resource "local_file" "demo" {
       name = "1.txt"
       content = "Hello World"
}'

Comment: @Ahmed Any code that I write, Azure, local etc, the terraform plan gets hung.